# Login to Discord and send slash command Python

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I want to log in to Discord with my account and send a slash command with it. I already have a code where I log in and send a message containing 'Hello World'. But now I want to trigger a slash command from another Bot with it. This is what I have so far:

```py
import requests

url = "url"
auth = {
    'authorization': 'token'
}
message = {
    'content': 'logged in'
}

requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=message)

command_data = {
    'name': 'imagine',
    'description': 'Create images with Midjourney',
    'options': [
        {
            'name': 'prompt',
            'description': 'The prompt to imagine',
            'type': 3,
            'required': True,
            'value': 'a cat'
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=auth, json=command_data)
```

but every time its send the logged in message and then gives me this error:

> {'message': 'Cannot send an empty message', 'code': 50006}

I've tried to change the content of the first message to the command (`/imagine a cat`) but that only sends in the command as message and not as slash command. I googled and didn't find anything that could help me besides the Discord API documentation I don't really understand how to use it in my case. I also asked ChatGPT but it only give me wrong solution.